# X11 forwarding from remote machine to windows host

Tags: x11-forwarding

I am trying to use MobaXterm and run some graphics examples on my remote embedded machine with Linux. I can get running OpenGL examples on target and display it properly.

Using MobaXterm (or putty) terminal I can connect to remote target and run the console then I set

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

I can execute and display app on target.

Now my intention is to execute & display it localy on my host therefore I use MobaXterm (putty) but it's not working.

```
Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
X Error of failed request:  BadRRCrtc (invalid Crtc parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RRGetCrtcInfo)
  Crtc id in failed request: 0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  13
  Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

What setting or configuration is missing to do X11 frowarding?

Comment: a.) Cygwin + ssh forwarding. b) local virtual machine with linux + ssh forwarding. Good luck. I doubt that OpenGl will be forwarded properly.

Comment: I have remote target (embedded machine+display) and now I am connect remotely to it via MobaXterm (and try putty as well) but your options a) or b) it's not fit